# How to display registered class based on three table

Tags: php, mysql

im still learning in php. Appreciate on your kindness. :)

```
<table style="width:100%;float:left">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Class ID</th>
<th>Subject</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Classroom</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Table name 'carts' :

```
<?php $query1=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from carts where status=1 and 
id='$id';")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

while($row_carts=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
{
$cartID = $row_carts['cartID'];           //cartID=3 in my database
```

Table name 'cartitems' :

```
$query2=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from cartitems where 
cartID='$cartID';")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$row_cartitems=mysqli_fetch_array($query2);                                                 
$classID = $row_cartitems['classID'];//classID=13 & classID=14 in mydatabase
```

Table name 'class_detail' :

```
$query3=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from class_detail where 
classID='$classID';")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$row_class_detail=mysqli_fetch_array($query3);

$subject_title = $row_class_detail['subject_title'];
$date = $row_class_detail['date'];
$time = $row_class_detail['time'];
$classroom_name = $row_class_detail['classroom_name'];
?>
```

To display information based of classID=13 and classID=14:

```
<tr class="show">
<td class="name">SS<?php echo $classID;?></td>                                  
<td><?php echo $subject_title; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $date;?></td>
<td><?php echo $time;?></td>
<td><?php echo $classroom_name;?></td>
</tr>       

<?php }?>                     
</table>
```

I want to display it like this:

```
Class ID| Subject  |    Day     |   Time    |Classroom|
--------+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
SS13    | ENGLISH  |  SUNDAY    | 2PM - 4PM |     G   |
SS14    | HISTORY  |  WEDNESDAY | 9AM - 11AM|     B   |
```

But the coding display it like this:

```
Class ID| Subject  |    Day     |   Time    |Classroom|
--------+----------+------------+-----------+---------+
SS13    | ENGLISH  |  SUNDAY    | 2PM - 4PM |     G   |
```

Comment: I think this is not database. only tables?

Comment: Use join and work with on query no need to write more complex database call and code.

Comment: I want to use array and for loop for my coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your code like this :

```
<?php

$query3=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from class_detail where 
classID='$classID';")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

while($row_class_detail=mysqli_fetch_array($query3))
{
?>

<tr class="show">
<td class="name">SS<?php echo $classID;?></td>                                  
<td><?php echo $row_class_detail['subject_title']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_class_detail['date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_class_detail['time']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_class_detail['classroom_name']; ?></td>
</tr>       

<?php
 }
?>
```

Hope it helps you.

Edit :

I created new array in cartitems while, you can take a look at code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%;float:left">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Class ID</th>
<th>Subject</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Classroom</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="stack";

$id=3;

$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db); 
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "Terjadi kesalahan koneksi";
}
$cartID=0;
$val=0;
$mylistuser=array();
$sql="SELECT * FROM carts WHERE id='$id' AND status='1'";
$run=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
while($row_carts=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
{
    $cartID = $row_carts['id'];    
}

 $sql2="SELECT * FROM cartitems WHERE cartID='$cartID'";
 $run2=mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);

while($row_carts2=mysqli_fetch_array($run2))
{

    $mylistuser[$val]['classID']=$row_carts2['classID'];
    $val++;
}

for($i=0;$i<count($mylistuser);$i++)
{
    $sql3="SELECT * FROM class_detail WHERE classID='".$mylistuser[$i]   
['classID']."'";
    $run3=mysqli_query($connect,$sql3);
    $row_carts3=mysqli_fetch_array($run3);
?>
    <tr>
        <td>SS<?php echo $row_carts3['classID']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_carts3['subject_title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_carts3['date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_carts3['time']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_carts3['classroom_name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is $mysqli variable?

Comment: to connect database?

Comment: I think you should create array of classID and call database again in html using for loop.

Comment: Alright if i use for loop, what condition should it be???

for($x=1; $x<//I dont know what condition should i put here ; $x++)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is sending the data only for one ID to your html table. In this case you are sending data for classID=13. If you want to display both, you need to send the data array to the html table, and then loop through the data and display the results.

Comment: I have try learn php array through w3schools.com but I still can't get it how to implement it to my coding.

Comment: So i can assign it like -->$x=0;
                  
    while($row_cartitems=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
     $x++;
                      
    $classID[$x] =  $row_cartitems['classID'];}

But how to make it loop?? I only know loop like this:

<?php for($x = 1; $x < //I don't know what to put here; $x++) { echo SS,$classID[$x]; echo "<br>";}?>